# How to change @Transactional order on a spring data repository method?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, spring-aop

I have custom annotation aspect @CreatedAtFilter which is applying filter before executing query.

```kotlin
@Target(FUNCTION)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
annotation class CreatedAtFilter(val daysCoverage: Int = 30)

@Aspect
@Order(2)
@Component
class CreatedAtFilterAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(CreatedAtFilter)")
    fun enableFilter(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
        val method = (joinPoint.signature as MethodSignature).method
        val days = method.getAnnotation(CreatedAtFilter::class.java).daysCoverage

        CreatedAtFilterApi.enable(days)
        logger.info { "Marking with $CREATED_AT_FILTER $days : $method" }
        return runCatching { joinPoint.proceed() }
            .also { CreatedAtFilterApi.clear() }
            .getOrThrow()
    }

    companion object : KLogging()
}
```

On application config a have set transaction aspect order = 1

```kotlin
@EnableTransactionManagement(order = 1)
```

On a simple class like this, ordering works correctly. Also, In debug mode inside `AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` is see transaction aspect and my custom aspect in correct orders.

```kotlin
@Component
open class Test {

    @Transactional // runs first
    @CreatedAtFilter // runs inside transaction
    open fun test() {
        logger.info { "TEST EXECUTION" }
    }
    companion object : KLogging()
}
```

But on a spring data repository spring interface, transaction always executing after any aspects, and i cannot see transaction aspect in `AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator`. So ordering is ignored on repository methods.

```kotlin
interface ProblemRepository : CrudRepository<Problem, Long> {

    @CreatedAtFilter
    @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
    fun findAll(): List<Problem>
}
```

Is not obvious why ordering is not working an repository, and is there any way to make this work?
Inside my custom aspect i already need a created transaction, otherwise my filter will not work. Creating transaction inside filter is not an a option.

Comment: I am no Spring person, so first I would like to know what the `ProblemRepository` implementation looks like. Moreover, are you aware of the fact, that annotations in Java are usually not inherited by subclasses or implementing classes, with one possible exception of classes bearing annotations which themselves bear an `@Inherited` annotation? But that never applies to annotated methods or interfaces, only class types.